# Close font-awesome button not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom-events

I have a close font-awesome icon inside a button like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    Feature A <i class="close-item fas fa-times"></i>
</button>
```

And since it is dynamically added to DOM I'm listening to click events on the icon like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-item', function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

The goal is to listen to click events on just the icon (not the rest of the button).
It works perfectly on Google Chrome but not in Firefox.
How can I make this work on Firefox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A click event within a button does not work in Firefox, you can just change the button to an `a` tag like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    Feature A <i class="close-item fas fa-times"></i>
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    Feature A <i class="close-item fas fa-times"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: It's probably the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.parent()` to select the button surrounding the icon:

```
$('.close-item').parent().click( function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

Comment: Want to list to click events just on the icon, not the rest of the button (updated the question). Thks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use fa class not fas

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Feature A <i class="close-item fa fa-times"></i> </button>
```

Here is working example

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i> <br><br>
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Comment: The fas tag is font awesome 5. Basically, you just downgraded the OP’s fontawesome version as a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending event object to function

```
$('.close-item').on('click', function(event e) {
    console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

Reffer questions:
[JavaScript onClick does not work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636925/javascript-onclick-does-not-work-in-firefox)
[jQuery click function not working on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745902/jquery-click-function-not-working-on-firefox)